# How to find default functions of wordpress

Tags: theme-development

How can I find all the default functions that are required for theme development.

Like for logo, widgets etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) would be the place to start.